# .htaccess Wildcard 301 redirect domain AND subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So, I'm running into this problem with this relatively complicated wildcard 301 redirect. My .htaccess-foo is terrible, so I'm hoping for some help here!

I need to change any uppercase to lowercase.

I need to change "gfoldername" to "g"

I need to replace any "-" with "_"

To show an example, this is what I'm trying to accomplish

```
 example.com/gfoldername/Another-Folder/

 to 

 example.com/g/another_folder/
```

I've tried quite a bit with no luck. Again, any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: 
Ended up resolving this myself with php. For those interested:

```
 $urls = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

 $url = explode('/',$urls);

 $f = $url[4];
 $f = strtolower($f);
 $f = str_replace("-", "_", $f);

 $url = "http://example.com/g/".$f;

 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
 header("Location: ".$url);
```

Comment: +1 For this much manipulation PHP is better place than mod_rewrite.